# NativeCall. How to get a string as a parameter of a C function

Tags: raku, nativecall

There is a C function which returns some string to a provided pointer:

```
void    snmp_error(netsnmp_session *sess, int *clib_errorno,
                       int *snmp_errorno, char **errstring);
```

The Perl6 version is:

```
sub snmp_error(Snmp-session, int32 is rw, int32 is rw, Str is rw) is native("netsnmp") { * };

snmp_error($sess, my int32 $errno, my int32 $liberr, my Str $errstr);
say $errno, " ", $liberr, " ", $errstr;
```

It returns correct ints but not a string:

> 0 -3 (Str)

Is it a just a bug or something is wrong here?

```
perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2016.12 built on MoarVM version 2016.12
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

The same is on

```
This is Rakudo version 2017.09 built on MoarVM version 2017.09.1
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I wrestled with the same problem I translated this:

```
gboolean notify_get_server_info (char **ret_name,
                                 char **ret_vendor,
                                 char **ret_version,
                                 char **ret_spec_version);
```

into this:

```
sub notify_get_server_info(Pointer[Str] $name is rw,
                           Pointer[Str] $vendor is rw,
                           Pointer[Str] $version is rw,
                           Pointer[Str] $spec_version is rw --> int32)
                           is native(LIB) { * }
```

which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug (or rather more likely just not fully implemented yet).

See the answers here for some work-arounds:
[Passing pointer to pointer in Perl 6 Nativecall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543217/passing-pointer-to-pointer-in-perl-6-nativecall/43553751)

Answer (score 0):

The method of Fernando Santagata works as intended:

```
sub snmp_error(Snmp-session, int32 is rw, int32 is rw, Pointer[Str] is rw) is native("netsnmp") { * };

my $e = Pointer[Str].new;
snmp_error($sess, my int32 $errno, my int32 $liberr, $e);
say "syserr=$errno liberr=$liberr error=", $e.deref;
```